# How to save an image in mysql database unsing ROR json API call for mobile application development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My json API is below
and I am using careerwave gem 
    { 
      "districtcity_id": 23, 
      "logo": "/home/amulyatanksale/Desktop/the_hulk.jpg", 
      "last_name": "Legend",
      "regionstate_id": 33, 
      "name": "John", 
      "role_id": 10, 
      "email": "jwsohny@gmail.com", 
      "password": "12345678", 
      "password_confirmation": "12345678", 
      "address": "cape town", 
      "firstplanid": 12, 
      "contactno": "7897875887",
      "is_auction_notification": true
    }

And it shows the following error

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/amulyatanksale/Desktop/the_hulk.jpg
```

But if run the same API on my local machine it is working
**Below is the code for call**

```
def create_user
begin
  Rails.logger.info "---------------ERROR WHILE REGISTER------#{params[:logo]}, #{params[:logo].split("/").last}"
  parse_image_data(params[:logo], params[:logo].split("/").last)
  @user = User.new(register_user_params)
        @user.save
  Rails.logger.info "---------------ERROR WHILE REGISTER------#{@user.to_json}"
    @subscribeplan = Subscription.create(user_id: @user.id, planid: params[:plan_id], name: params[:sub_name], description: params[:description], price: params[:price], is_free: params[:is_free], totalpartscount: params[:totalpartscount] , startdate: Date.today, enddate: Date.today + 1.months)
  @subscribeplan.save
  @plan_id = @user.subscriptions.first.planid rescue nil
  user_type = @user.role.nil? ? "" : @user.role.name
  user_state = @user.regionstate.nil? ? "" : @user.regionstate.name
  user_city = @user.districtcity.nil? ? "" : @user.districtcity.name
  render status: 200, json: { result: :success, message: "Buyer Created.", first_name: @user.name, last_name: @user.last_name, email: @user.email, password: @user.password, logo: @user.logo, phone_no: @user.contactno, address: @user.address, user_type: user_type, registration_date: @user.created_at.to_date, state: user_state, city:user_city, email_auction_notification: @user.is_auction_notification, approval_status: @user.is_approved, user_id: @user.id, subscription_plan: @plan_id }   
rescue Exception => e
  Rails.logger.info "---------------ERROR WHILE REGISTER------#{@user.to_json}"
  Rails.logger.info "---------------ERROR WHILE REGISTER------#{e.to_json}"
    render status: 400, json: {errors: @user.errors.messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

end

def parse_image_data(base64_image, img_name)
      if img_name
            begin
              uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({

```
            :tempfile => File.new(Rails.root.join(base64_image)),
            :filename => img_name,
            :type => Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extname(img_name)[1..-1]).to_s
          })
        rescue Exception => e
        end     
        params[:register_user][:logo] =  uploaded_file
  end
```

Comment: Your JSON includes a path to an image instead of the image itself. If the API is on the same machine than the client, then this might work, because the server would be able to read that image from the same path. But if the API is running on a different machine this cannot work, because the file doesn't exist at the path you send to the API. You need to upload the image to the API to make this work. Please show the code you use to generate the JSON and the code in the API consuming the hash.

Comment: `"/home/amulyatanksale/Desktop/the_hulk.jpg"` is a string, not a file. The API needs to accept a **file** parameter if it's going to work for uploads.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @spickerman, I have  updated query with the code as well, please suggest I am wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the path to the file so that is because it works in your local only. You need to submit the form as "multipart/form-data

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files